# Show image from fetched data using openCV

Tags: python, opencv, scikit-learn, mnist

I've been using datasets from sklearn. And I want to show image from 'MNIST original' using openCV.imshow

Here is part of my code

```
dataset = datasets.fetch_mldata('MNIST original')
features = np.array(dataset.data, 'int16')
labels = np.array(dataset.target, 'int')



list_hog_fd = []
deskewed_images = []
for img in features:
     cv2.imshow("digit", img)
     deskewed_images.append(deskew(img))
```

"digit" window appears but it is definitely not an digit image. How can I access real image from dataset?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Shape

MNIST image datasets generally are distributed and used as a 1D vector of 784 values.

However, in order to show it as image, you need to convert it to a 2D matrix with 28*28 values.

Simply using `img = img.reshape(28,28)` might work in your case.

Comment: Thanks for answer but strange thing happens now. Namely it is still not shown with cv,imshow as it should , but when I click "view as array" in PyCharm i can see different colored pixel as cells in 2D array which form numbers.